# How to understand the vuejs lifecycle better

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to better understand Vuejs lifecycles. [The documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html) is short and I guess assumes most people are familiar with the lifecycle concept.

However, I've only been using `created(){}` as it suits my need to initialize a function/data (to put it vaguely) when the "page is loaded".

But I am sure every lifecycle hook has its own distinct feature or purpose. So, I am hoping someone can provide a better intro/example of when each hook can be used from the context of page load to page finish.

To put it simply. When you request a web page, there are two observable steps

1: page is loading
2: page finished loading.

My question is, when do the `created`, `mounted`, `updated` and `destroyed` hooks take place within those two stages? I didn't mention the before/after hooks as they are obvious by their meaning.

Comment: Are you looking for this? https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram

Comment: He / she's already linked that page

Comment: Yeah, I already linked that @3000. I am looking for a better intro than that one

Comment: @hidar: https://alligator.io/vuejs/component-lifecycle/ ?

Comment: @hidar if you want details of page load, you can make use of javascript events.https://javascript.info/onload-ondomcontentloaded . Vuejs life cycle hooks are related to component states and not state of the page.

Comment: @divine Are you sure about this? I thought it was when inserts everything it generates into the #app element of the page. I thought the lifecycle were about when this element is made ... so if I don't use any component then there is no lifecycle? I'm sure this is not the case

Comment: In a single-page app, is the page ever really finished loading?

Comment: @hidar vuejs life cycle hooks are for detecting change of state in components. in SPA , page loads only once. But the State of the components get changed and change of state can be detected by vuejs lifecycle hooks.

Answer (score 0):

Lifecycle hooks relate to a Vue instance, not to a page load. Components are Vue instances, as is the main Vue instance that is typically called on the whole page.

The diagram gives a pretty good rundown of where each hook sits in relation to what is going on on the instance. In simple terms, `created` happens before you have DOM to work with, and all the others happen after.

Comment: Understand more about Vue 3 lifecycle  [vue 3 lifecyle hooks with real-time example](https://blog.canopas.com/vue-3-lifecycle-hooks-with-real-time-example-1b772b89e085).